# CSS hover trigger of underlaying layer and top layer

Tags: html, css

How to make a css hover transition for both layers. I wrote the whole page so that you can (copy/paste) try it from your computer desktop. What I have works, but can it be done without javascript/jQuery with pure CSS? I tried with CSS pointer-events and was able to transition either the top layer (#circleOuter) or the underlaying layer (#circleInner) but not both layers. For this to work, #circleOuter:hover has to trigger #circleInner. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#circleOuter").hover(function(){
                $("#circleInner").css("transform","rotate(180deg)");
                $("#circleOuter").css("transform","rotate(-180deg)");
            }, function(){
                $("#circleInner").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
                $("#circleOuter").css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
            });
        });
        </script>
        <style>
            #circleWrap
                {
                background:#ff0;
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
                position:relative;
                }

            #circleInner
                {
                background:url(http://socalsky.com/_/images/mis/circle_inner.png) center center/ 188px 188px no-repeat;
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
                position:absolute;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
                transition: 500ms ease all;
                }

            #circleOuter
                {
                background:url(http://socalsky.com/_/images/mis/circle_outer.png) center center/ 200px 200px no-repeat;
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
                position:absolute;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
                transition: 500ms ease all;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="circleWrap">
            <div id="circleInner">
            </div>
            <div id="circleOuter">
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your actual example I don't see the need to trigger the event on **hover** the `#circleOuter:hover` if both elements are the size of the container and trigger at the same time just use the parent to trigger it:

```css
#circleWrap {
  background: #ff0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#circleInner {
  background: url(http://socalsky.com/_/images/mis/circle_inner.png) center center/ 188px 188px no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 500ms ease all;
}

#circleOuter {
  background: url(http://socalsky.com/_/images/mis/circle_outer.png) center center/ 200px 200px no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 500ms ease all;
}
#circleWrap:hover  #circleInner{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#circleWrap:hover  #circleOuter{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="circleWrap">
  <div id="circleInner">
  </div>
  <div id="circleOuter">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds really good too DaniP, going to try this aswel, give me a few to try all this out. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It's probably been a year since a asked a question. How do I mark the answers as correct answers again?

Comment: @Kobbe you can see a check mark in gray under the votes at the left side of the answer you want to mark

Comment: Seems only one answer can be selected. Well, I did up-vote everybody who answered the questions, three answers and two different approaches. Thank you some much everyone. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Kobbe yep just one and thanks for the upvotes you can choose the one you think was more usefull . De nada :)

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me. check the plunkr out . done using pure css ---> https://plnkr.co/edit/FQkBWUNJ79q43eknO7p9?p=preview

```
#circleWrap:hover>#circleInner{
transform: rotate(180deg);
}

#circleWrap:hover>#circleOuter{
 transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Comment: Alright, going to try this right now. Thanks ihavCoder.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

just add below css and remove jquery.

```
#circleWrap:hover>#circleInner
    {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: 500ms ease all;
    }

    #circleWrap:hover>#circleOuter
    {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transition: 500ms ease all;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: my pleasure @Kobbe